# Netbeans 7 + Tomcat 7 start detection

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, startup

I am using Netbeans with Tomcat 7 server (the one embedded in instalation). Whenever I start the server, netbeans starts bombarding my application with requests:

/netbeans-tomcat-status-test

and my app returns 404 (i dont have this page) and fails to detect its startup (in services I see the server as offline)...is there any way to workaround this bogus behaviour or is it some configuration issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans 7.2 seems not to do this: it hits that url on application startup, but only once.

Sadly under the profiler I see the same thing you report.  Rather annoying.